# How to merge from tracking branch without naming the branch?

Tags: git, branch

I usually update my local branch like this:

```
$ git fetch

$ git status
# On branch develop
# Your branch is behind 'origin/develop' by 1 commit, and can be fast-forwarded.
#
nothing to commit (working directory clean)

$ git merge --ff-only origin/develop
```

Is there anyway to write that last command without naming the remote branch? From the git status is obvious that git know that the current branch is tracking origin/develop. So I'm looking for something like:

```
$ git merge tracking
```

The reason for this is that it easy to type in the wrong branch when switching back and forth (as you can see I use `--ff-only` as a safe-guard here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `develop@{upstream}` or the shorter `develop@{u}` to refer to the branch that is set as the upstream for your `develop` branch. If no branch name is supplied before the `@` it will default to using the current branch, so while you're on that branch you can use just `@{u}`.

These types of references will work for other commands as well as for merge, for instance you can get a list of commits that would be applied by the merge with the command:

```
git log ..@{u}
```

This is documented in the man page for [git rev-parse](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-parse.html), in the section about **specifying revisions**.

Comment: I think this is the most correct answer as `@{upstream} = tracking` here

Answer (score 3):

Set the option `merge.defaultToUpstream` to true:

```
git config merge.defaultToUpstream true
```

and than you can ommit the commit you want to merge with:

```
git merge --ff-only
```